# Convert Spotfire calculated column to PowerBi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, calculated-columns, spotfire

I am converting a Spotfire dashboard to Power BI and am struggling on how to convert one of my calculated columns:

```
CASE  
WHEN MostCommon(If([Language]="English (UK)",[Training title])) OVER ([Internal Course Code]) IS NULL THEN MostCommon(If([Language]="Dutch (The Netherlands)",[Training title])) OVER ([Internal Course Code])
ELSE MostCommon(If([Language]="English (UK)",[Training title])) OVER ([Internal Course Code])
END
```

**Situation:** some courses are available in several languages. So the [Training title] differs but the content is the same, only the language differs. But the system sees it as different courses. In my visualizations I would like to group the courses together (irrespective of the language). This can be done with the column [Internal Course Code]. However, [Internal Course Code] is not meaningful to end users, so I would like to create a new column in which I include the [Training Title] next to the [Internal Course Code]. Since there are different titles for the Internal Course Codes I would like to show the (1) English Titles. In some cases there is no English title, then I would like to show the Dutch Title.

In Spotfire I used the OVER-function. Does anyone have a suggestion how to write this down in PowerBI?

Any help or guidance would be very much appreciated!

**Sample data & desired output:**

| Internal Course Code | Training Title | Language | DESIRED OUTPUT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | Optimism 101 | English (UK) | Optimism 101 |
| 100 | Optimisme voor beginners | Dutch (The Netherlands) | Optimism 101 |
| 100 | Optimisme, mode d'emploi | French (France) | Optimism 101 |
| 139 | Digitale transformatie | Dutch (The Netherlands) | Digitale transformatie |
| 169 | Prendre la parole en public | French (France) | Presentation Skills |
| 169 | Presentation Skills | English (UK) | Presentation Skills |
| 169 | Presenteren | Dutch (The Netherlands) | Presentation Skills |
| 186 | Glashelder leiderschap | Dutch (The Netherlands) | Glashelder leiderschap |
| 81 | Beïnvloeden | Dutch (The Netherlands) | Influencing |
| 81 | Influencer | French (France) | Influencing |
| 81 | Influencing | English (UK) | Influencing |

Comment: Please share your sample data as copiable text and desired output.

Comment: Hi David, thank you for your comment. I included some sample data and the desired output. Hope this clarifies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. Make sure to change #"Changed Type" in the custom column to whatever the name of your previous step is.

Source table:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Custom column:

[image]

Custom column code:

```
let rows = 
Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", (x)=> x[Internal Course Code] = _[Internal Course Code] and (Text.StartsWith(x[Language], "English") or Text.StartsWith(x[Language], "Dutch"))), 
sorted = Table.Sort(rows, {"Language", Order.Descending})

in sorted[Training Title]{0}
```

Full query

```
  let
        Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("jZFBS8QwEIX/ytCTQg+twrpeRVdEUEE9rXvINm/bwemkJOn+LX+Ef8y0orBo6Z5CmPe9Ny9Zr7OyKCjLs8cucsuhpbIoh/uN1sKhoZPX+1PKNvkfIWjvnKctalaFD8Psuo9VQl4a0ANiAy9GbZjgc2qdBdm3vijOLtB24ngQrDx0cFl5oxV+4PPLMYBrjkZAMQ3DzvnWRMZ89GKkn5Kz9SAx1Bnvkg2Uun4rXE0H/6IBGlOaU3p+Z5Ew8UoHeiTL+e2Wi0FzKyY0EAtPAk5HqBrTzdLL8buu8Pmhe3GwRwR+I3e6kz41TnlT5Q+FrPU/nTdf", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"Internal Course Code" = _t, #"Training Title" = _t, Language = _t]),
        #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Internal Course Code", Int64.Type}, {"Training Title", type text}, {"Language", type text}}),
        #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each let rows = 
            Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", (x)=> x[Internal Course Code] = _[Internal Course Code] and (Text.StartsWith(x[Language], "English") or Text.StartsWith(x[Language], "Dutch"))), 
            sorted = Table.Sort(rows, {"Language", Order.Descending})
    
            in sorted[Training Title]{0})
    in
        #"Added Custom"
```